# Unable to show pdf file in browser using response object

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, devexpress, httpresponse

The pdf file I am generating using Dev Express and returning it to the browser using response object. I need to open file in the browser new window.

For the client side script the code to call method of web service:

```
window.open(dashboardService + "PrintableJobOrderDocument?JobOrderNo=" + jobOrderNo, "Job Order Documnet", "scrollbars=0,fullscreen=1", false);
```

For the WCF service the method is:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void PrintableJobOrderDocument(string JobOrderNo)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobOrderNo))
    {
        CommonServiceClient commonService = null;
        try
        {
            commonService = new CommonServiceClient();
            var data = commonService.JobOrderPDFDoc(JobOrderNo);
            if (data.Count() != 0)
            {
                //Excel file as a memory stream
                var excel = JobOrderTemplate(data);//this method will return the workbook object.
                MemoryStream ExcelStream = new MemoryStream();
                excel.SaveDocument(ExcelStream, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
                ExcelStream.Position = 0;

                //Excel file to a pdf memory stream
                Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                workbook.LoadDocument(ExcelStream, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
                MemoryStream PDFStream = new MemoryStream();
                workbook.ExportToPdf(PDFStream);
                PDFStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.BufferOutput = true;
                response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "Job Order No. " + JobOrderNo + ".pdf");
                byte[] fileToDownload = PDFStream.ToArray();
                response.BinaryWrite(fileToDownload);
                response.Flush();
                response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GeneralTask.AddMessageLog(MessageLogApplication.Portal, MessageLogModules.Common, MessageLogType.Error, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            ServiceHelper.CloseService(commonService);
        }
    }
}
```

The response object show different behavior to different browser.
Like for:

**Chrome:** File some time opened and some time unable to open the file.

**Mozilla:** File never opened and give me error:

> C:\Users\tach\AppData\Local\Temp\nJ0oODH4.pdf.part could not be saved,
>   because the source file could not be read.
>
> Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

**Response Header in Mozilla:**

> Cache-Control: private 
>   
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type:
>   
>   application/pdf Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
>   
>   Content-Disposition: Job
>   Order No. ad_0003.pdf 
>   
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?RzpcRm1zMlRmc1xGTVNPZmZpY2UtVjEwNi1UcnVua1xGTVNQb3J0YWxcRGFzaGJvYXJkU2VydmljZS5zdmNcUHJpbnRhYmxlSm9iT3JkZXJEb2N1bWVudA==?=
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Date: Thu, 08 Jun
>   2017 09:48:00 GMT

**Microsoft Edge:** File never open.

I have the checked all the browsers Network tab and in header response file, file type, file name available but unable to open the file.

**Update:**

Below given *AppHeader* works for **Chrome** but not for Firefox or Edge.

```
response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; \"Job Order No " + JobOrderNo + ".pdf\"");
```

and

```
response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "Job Order No. " + JobOrderNo + ".pdf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support in all browsers, I've just changed my code from viewing the file to download the file and instead of using `AppendHeader`, I am using `AddHeader` to set the response header properties. As according to **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader(v=vs.110).aspx):**

> **HttpResponse.AddHeader Method (String, String)** - Adds an HTTP header to the output stream. *AddHeader is provided for
>   compatibility with earlier versions of ASP*.

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Job Order No " + JobOrderNo + ".pdf");
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", PDFStream.Length.ToString());
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.Flush();
response.BinaryWrite(PDFStream.ToArray());
response.End();
```

I think this solved my problem because it provide compatibility with earlier versions of ASP.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "Job Order No. " + JobOrderNo + ".pdf");
```

to:

```
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; \"Job Order No " + JobOrderNo + ".pdf\"");
```

Does that help?

Comment: just worked in chrome but firefox now have different problem.

Comment: I don't understand what that image is - you'll need to explain it a bit more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146347/discussion-between-mjwills-and-shahzad-mirza).

Comment: thanks for your help. Kindly see my answer that worked for me.